# How to refactor regex in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following sentences:

> ```
>      text <MIR-1> GGG-33 <EXP-V-3> text text <VACCVIRUS-PROP-1> some other.
>      text <MIR-1> text <ASSC-PHRASE-1> text <VACCVIRUS-PROP-1> some other <PATTERN-1> other.
> ```

What I want to do is to create a *single* regular expression (regex) that can match
the two sentences above. Note that the only differing pattern in the above sentences
are the middle factor `<EXP-V-3>` and `<ASSC-PHRASE-1>`.

I'm stucked with the current attempt, which matched them in two redundant regex.
What's the right way to do it?

```
 use Data::Dumper;

    @sent = ("text <MIR-1> GGG-33 <EXP-V-3> text text <VACCVIRUS-PROP-1> some other.",
             " text <MIR-1> text <ASSC-PHRASE-1> text <VACCVIRUS-PROP-1> some other <PATTERN-1> other.");


    foreach $sent (@sent) {
       if ( $sent =~ /.*<MIR-\d+>.*<EXP-V-\d+>.*<VACCVIRUS-PROP-\d+>.*/gi ) {

          print "$sent\n";
        }
        elsif( $sent =~ /.*<MIR-\d+>.*<ASSC-PHRASE-\d+>.*<VACCVIRUS-PROP-\d+>/gi ) {
         print "$sent\n";
        }
    }
```

**[Live demo](https://eval.in/38486)**

Comment: So, do you now about `|` - `choose`- metasymbol? I think it could helps you

Comment: `(?:xxx|yyy)\s*<MIR-1>\s*(?:xxx|yyy)\s*(?:<EXP-V-3>|<ASSC-PHRASE-1>)\s*(?:xxxx|yyy)\s*<VACCVIRUS-PROP-1>`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(?:xxx|yyy)\s*<MIR-1>\s*(?:xxx|yyy)\s*(?:<EXP-V-3>|<ASSC-PHRASE-1>)\s*(?:xxxx|yyy)\s*<VACCVIRUS-PROP-1>`

Maybe this regexp not optimized, but it work.

Ok, what I do here:

First Magic:

```
(?:EXPR) - Capture group NOT CAPTURED # <?:> helps to avoid any capturing
```

Second Magic:

```
(a|b|c) - choose metasymbol in work. I would choose between <a> or <b> or <c>
```

Third Magic:

[Here Rubular work](http://rubular.com/r/521rAcfeF6)

Generalization:

```
.+?\s*<MIR-\d+>\s*.+?\s*(?:<EXP-V-\d+>|<ASSC-PHRASE-\d+>)\s*.+?\s*<VACCVIRUS-PROP-\d+>.+
```

And your example:

[Here Rubular work too](http://rubular.com/r/CEiZdjhmbA)

Reject string:

```
.+?\s*<MIR-\d+>\s*[^\[]+?\s*(?:<EXP-V-\d+>|<ASSC-PHRASE-\d+>)\s*[^\]]+?\s*<VACCVIRUS-PROP-\d+>.+
```

Fourth Magic:

```
[^SYMBOLS] - Class of symbols. <^> At the beginning mean 'I DON'T want match them'.
```

Here Example:

```
[abc]{1} - I will match <a> or <b> or <c>
[^abc]{1} - I will NOT match <a> or <b> or <c>
```

[Here Rubular work again](http://rubular.com/r/FE5iAjRLkj)

Comment: How can I make it more general? As 'xxx'or 'yyy' can actually be anything.

Comment: oh, sorry, yes, xxx and yyy i take from your example. if you want, you could put anything here. please, provide more examples, what you want to match

Comment: Thanks a million. One last thing. How can I make it *reject* the following string `text <MIR-1> text [[express]<EXP-V-0>ion]<EXP-N-0> text <VACCVIRUS-PROP-1> some other <PATTERN-1> other.`

Comment: i.e. the `EXP-V-\d+` pattern should be unique and followed by white space and no subsequent `]`.

Comment: please, check update again. Don't forget accept answer at the end ;)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33959/discussion-between-neversaint-and-loldop)

Answer (score 0):

Refactor what you have

```
@sent = ("text <MIR-1> GGG-33 <EXP-V-3> text text <VACCVIRUS-PROP-1> some other.",
         " text <MIR-1> text <ASSC-PHRASE-1> text <VACCVIRUS-PROP-1> some other <PATTERN-1> other.");

foreach $sent (@sent) {
   if ( $sent =~ /.*<MIR-\d+>.*<(?:EXP-V|ASSC-PHRASE)-\d+>.*<VACCVIRUS-PROP-\d+>.*/gi ) {
      print "$sent\n";
    }
}
```

Where

```
.*<MIR-\d+>.*<EXP-V-\d+>.*<VACCVIRUS-PROP-\d+>.*|.*<MIR-\d+>.*<ASSC-PHRASE-\d+>.*<VACCVIRUS-PROP-\d+>.*
```

becomes

```
.*<MIR-\d+>.*<(?:EXP-V|ASSC-PHRASE)-\d+>.*<VACCVIRUS-PROP-\d+>.*
```

Use regex refactor software http://regexformat.com

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/TiXXO6/1